# Highlighting Kit/Package components on a picking ticket

Tags: netsuite

I have a customer wanting kit components to be highlighted or specially formatted on a Picking Ticket with an advanced PDF.

I can format the parent with no problem, but the customer wants the components to display in a different background colour. (custom column field indicating a Kit item, then using <#if> on the form to change to Bold...

But i can't find a field or criteria to tell the template if the item in question is a KIT COMPONENT??

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for those who may be interested, I found a way to differentiate between kit parent and kit component on a Picking Ticket Advanced PDF Template.

Firstly, create a transaction column field. Check Box; Stored Value; Sale Item/IF;HIDDEN;Default is CHECKED.

During sales order entry, this field will be "checked" by default. However, as the kit components do not appear on the sales order entry, they will not inherit the default value and thus will remain NULL.

In the advanced PDF template, I did the following:

```
<#assign committed="${item.quantitycommitted}"/><#if committed="0"><#assign committed=''/></#if>
<#if item.custcol_notcomponent='T'>
    <#if item.custcolitemtype="Kit/Package"><tr style="font-weight:bold">
    <#else><tr style="font-weight:normal"></#if>
    <td width="15%" class="item" font-size="7pt">${item.item}</td>
    <td width="20%" class="item" align="center">${item.binnumber}</td>
    <td width="40%" class="item">${item.description}</td>
    <td width="8%" class="item" align="center">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td width="8%" class="item" align="center">${committed}</td>
    <td width="8%" class="item">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" class="item">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<#else>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%" class="kititem" font-size="7pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${item.item}</td>
    <td width="20%" class="kititem" align="center">${item.binnumber}</td>
    <td width="40%" class="kititem">${item.description}</td>
    <td width="8%" class="kititem" align="center">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td width="8%" class="kititem" align="center">${committed}</td>
    <td width="8%" class="kititem">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" class="kititem">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</#if>
```

The result, is a picking ticket with BOLD kit parents, greyed and indented kit components, and just regular black text for standard inventory items.

Something like this for the transaction lines:

[image: image sample]

Hope this helps someone out sometime :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution but it won't indent. Looks like it doesn't go to the <#else> part.

```html
<#if item.custcol_f5_not_component = 'T'>
          <#if item.custcol_item_type="Kit/Package"><tr style="font-weight:bold"><#else><tr style="font-weight:normal"></#if>
          <td colspan="5">${item.custcol_f5_item}</td>
          <td colspan="7">${item.description}</td>
          <td colspan="2">${item.custcol_skl_bin_location}</td>
          <td align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity}</td>
          <td align="center" colspan="2">${item.units}</td>
          <td align="center" colspan="3"><b>${item.quantitycommitted}</b></td>
          <td align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantitybackordered}</td>
      </tr>
  <#else>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="padding-left:10px;">${item.custcol_f5_item}</td>
          <td colspan="7">${item.description}</td>
          <td colspan="2">${item.custcol_skl_bin_location}</td>
          <td align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity}</td>
          <td align="center" colspan="2">${item.units}</td>
          <td align="center" colspan="3"><b>${item.quantitycommitted}</b></td>
          <td align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantitybackordered}</td>
      </tr>
  </#if>
```

Comment: Double check you have set the default value correctly and the field names are correct

Comment: Probably too late for you, but might help someone else. 

I found whilst trying to use a packing slip template that the reference is back to the sales order. For some reason the custom field was not pulling through from there, when I updated the template to pull from the item fulfillment it correctly referenced the custom field.