# How to indent kit component items on Advanced PDF packing slip

Tags: formatting, netsuite, freemarker

I am setting up a customized packing slip form via Advanced PDFs in NetSuite and need help fulfilling a certain formatting request. I am having trouble with the placement of the code to indent only kit items and not their components. NetSuite will not accept my changes on the form due to the misplacement of #list and #if tags. If someone could assist clearing this issue up for me by showing an example of what that should look like, it would be most appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed here and thanks! -Ryan I have tried placing the code before and after the #list tag.

```
<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="12">${salesorder.item[0].item@label}</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${salesorder.item[0].quantityordered@label}</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${salesorder.item[0].quantityremaining@label}</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${salesorder.item[0].quantity@label}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
        <#list salesorder.item as tranline> //callout to list items from item fulfillment
            <#if tranline.custcol_9r_noncomponent='T'> //checks to see if items are kits items or not
                <#if tranline.custcolitemtype="Kit/Package"><tr style="font-weight:bold"> //bolds kit items
                  <#else><tr style="font-weight:normal"> //if not kit item, uses normal formatting
    </#if> //for kit items use this formatting
                <td width="15%" class="item" font-size="7pt">${tranline.item}</td>
                <td width="20%" class="item">${tranline.description}</td>
                <td width="8%" class="item" align="center">${tranline.quantityremaining}</td>
                <td width="8%" class="item" align="center">${tranline.quantity}</td>
                <td width="8%" class="item">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="9%" class="item">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                    <#else> //for component items, use this formatting
                <tr>
                <td width="15%" class="kititem" font-size="7pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${tranline.item}</td>
                <td width="20%" class="kititem">${tranline.description}</td>
                <td width="8%" class="kititem" align="center">${tranline.quantityremaining}</td>
                <td width="8%" class="kititem" align="center">${tranline.quantity}</td>
                <td width="8%" class="kititem">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="9%" class="kititem">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </#if> //should refer to tranline.custcol_9r_noncomponent='T'statement
              </#list> //should close the callout for list items
              </table> //ends table
```

Comment: Hi there, could you add some spacing and carriage returns to your question? It's quite a wall.

Comment: See Steve's answer here: [Highlighting Kit/Package components on a picking ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290680/highlighting-kit-package-components-on-a-picking-ticket/49481594#49481594).  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Krypton Hi there. I actually took a look at Steve's code but am not sure the best place to input the code in the Packing Slip template. The error I am getting is below:                                         Can't compare values of these types. Allowed comparisons are between two numbers, two strings, two dates, or two booleans.
Left hand operand is a hash+boolean (wrapper: com.netledger.templates.model.BooleanModel).
Right hand operand is a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar).
The blamed expression:
==> tranline.custcol_9r_noncomponent='T' [in template "template" at line 154, column 18]

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit; it's saying the comparison doesn't make sense because one side's a boolean (true/false) and the other is a string.  Try changing that expression to `tranline.custcol_9r_noncomponent = true`.